# FrontPage Cannot Publish One Specific Web Page

Tags: caching, deployment, content-management-system, publish, frontpage

I have a web site that is designed and published using FrontPage 2003. I have changed 5 web pages in that web site. When I publish them, FrontPage doesn't show any error messages. I find that 4 of the web pages are published correctly, but one is not. The web site still has the old version of that web page in it.

I have tried deleting the old version from both FrontPage and from my published web site. But the problem comes right back as soon as I publish the web page with the same name. For example, here's how I deleted the old version:

1. Have a new version ready (such as web-page-TEST.htm).
2. Delete the old version from FrontPage.
3. Publish the web site. When FrontPage offers to remove the old
   version that is still in the published web site, I tell FrontPage
   to delete it.
4. Rename the new version to use the original web page name (such
   as web-page.htm).
5. Publish the web page again. When FrontPage offers me to remove the
   TEST version that is still in the published web site, I tell
   FrontPage to delete it.
6. When I use browser to open the web page, I find that it still
   contains the old info.

I am quite sure that the content in web-page-X is correct. The reason is that I had published it under a different web page name (like web-page-X-TEST.htm), and it could be published without any problem, and it also worked fine.

I have run out of ideas. Please help. Thanks.

Jay Chan

Answer (score 0):

In Folders view, right-click the file that is not published, and then click Don't Publish to cancel the selection. If that doesn't work, here are some other troubleshooting tips which may help:

- [Web site changes are not visible on the destination Web server in FrontPage 2003 or in SharePoint Designer 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828904)